# using Google Maps API with auocomplete textview to search

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-places-api

i want the maps like search view where we search places To and From (when we start typing the name of the street, the details of the street should be displayed below with the help of autocomplete Text view)i am using the Places API but its not working as i want
Java.Class

```
public class GpsLocation extends Activity implements
        LocationListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    AutoCompleteTextView autocomplete_places;
    Button auto, next;
    private static final String TAG = "GpsLocation";
    private static final long INTERVAL = 10000 * 10;
    private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 10000 * 5;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mCurrentLocation;
    String mLastUpdateTime;
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editorpref;
    GPSTracker gps;
    private PlaceAutoCompleteAdapter mAdapter;
    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        createLocationRequest();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
        setContentView(R.layout.location);
        autocomplete_places = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_places);
        auto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.auto);
        next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);

        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        autocomplete_places.setAdapter(new PlaceArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.autocomplete_list_item));
        autocomplete_places.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String description = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        auto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                gps = new GPSTracker(getApplicationContext());
                if (gps.canGetLocation()){
                    updateUI();
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
                }else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(GpsLocation.this);
                    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");
                    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");
                    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
                    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
                if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
                    finish();
                }
                }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart fired ..............");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop fired ..............");
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        Log.d(TAG, "isConnected ...............: " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
    }

    private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
            return true;
        } else {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 0).show();
            return false;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnected - isConnected ...............: " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
        startLocationUpdates();

    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        Log.d(TAG, "Location update started ..............: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Connection failed: " + connectionResult.toString());
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        Log.d(TAG, "UI update initiated .............");
        if (null != mCurrentLocation) {
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()));
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()));
            Log.d("Location", String.valueOf(lat + lng));
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
                String city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
                Toast.makeText(GpsLocation.this, city, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "location is null ...............");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mCurrentLocation = location;
        mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        updateUI();
    }
}
```

PlaceArray Adapter.class

```
public class PlaceArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {

    ArrayList<String> resultList;

    Context mContext;
    int mResource;

    PlaceApi mPlaceAPI = new PlaceApi();

    public PlaceArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);

        mContext = context;
        mResource = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Last item will be the footer
        return resultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return resultList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    resultList = mPlaceAPI.autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                    filterResults.values = resultList;
                    filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                }

                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, Filter.FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };

        return filter;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.autocomplete_list_item, null);

        if (position != (resultList.size() - 1)) {
            TextView autocompleteTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.autocompleteText);
            autocompleteTextView.setText(resultList.get(position));
        }


        return view;
    }


}
```

Comment: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-autocompletetextview-with-google-places-autocomplete-api/   Try this blog.

Comment: You may read [this](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete) in case you ever miss something. You can have two options for this: [Embed a PlaceAutocompleteFragment or a SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#option_1_embed_a_placeautocompletefragment_or_a_supportplaceautocompletefragment) and [Use an intent to launch the autocomplete activity](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#option_2_use_an_intent_to_launch_the_autocomplete_activity). The first option is what you may be missing.